# Changing SELECT query into UPDATE query (Parsing JSON)

Tags: json, sql-server-2017

I'm working on some API info collecting and I've written a program that reads the domains and looks up the API info and after it finds the info it puts the whole JSON text it made into a column `JSONDATA` in Microsoft SQL server table `[dbo].[NoveDomeneAUG]`. Domain list is stored in the same table under the column name called `DomainsNew`

I have this statement that I would need to change into an UPDATE query or make it work as an UPDATE query meaning it would read the data from `JSONDATA` column and store the parsed data in new columns.

```
 SELECT * 
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.domain') AS Domain,
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.name') AS CompanyName
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.legalName') AS legalName
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.sector') AS CategorySector
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.industryGroup') AS CategoryIndustryGroup
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.industry') AS CategoryIndustry
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.subIndustry') AS CategorySubIndustry
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.sicCode') AS CategorySicCode
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.category.naicsCode') AS CategoryNaicsCode
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.metrics.employees') AS EmployeesNumber
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.metrics.employeesRange') AS EmployeesRange
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.metrics.marketCap') AS MarketCap
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.metrics.annualRevenue') AS AnnualRevenue
 , JSON_VALUE(JSONDATA, '$.parent.domain') AS ParentDomain
   FROM dbo.NoveDomeneAUG;
```

The columns the SELECT query makes can be either copied to the same table or another table. This query would make all the columns i need to fill in `[NoveDomeneAUG]`.

```
ALTER TABLE [Domainbank].[dbo].[NoveDomeneAUG] ADD
    Domain nvarchar(50),
    CompanyName nvarchar(50),
    legalName nvarchar(50),
    CategorySector nvarchar(50),
    CategoryIndustryGroup nvarchar(50),
    CategoryIndustry nvarchar(50),
    CategorySubIndustry nvarchar(50),
    CategorySicCode nvarchar(50),
    CategoryNaicsCode nvarchar(50),
    EmployeesNumber nvarchar(50),
    EmployeesRange nvarchar(50),
    MarketCap nvarchar(50),
    AnnualRevenue nvarchar(50),
    ParentDomain nvarchar(50);
```

*This is how the table should look after the update statement has been ran (Domain column is missing since this is an older picture*
 [image: Picture example:]
Datatypes can all be set to `varchar` or `nvarchar`

This is how one of the JSON output looks:

```
    {
  "id": "3e3562a7-b160-4fd8-a190-8ca0a5288794",
  "name": "Garmin",
  "legalName": "Garmin Ltd.",
  "domain": "garmin.com",
  "domainAliases": [
    "garmin.de",
    "garmin.se",
    "garmin.si",
    "garmin.nl",
    "garmin.dk",
    "garmin.it",
    "garmin.fi",
    "garmin.no",
    "garmin.hr",
    "garmin.at",
    "garmin.pl",
    "garmin.cl",
    "garmin.com.au",
    "garmin.co.uk",
    "garmin.be",
    "garminconnect.com",
    "garmin.com.mx",
    "garminservice.de",
    "garmin.es",
    "garminasus.com",
    "garminonline.de",
    "opencaching.com",
    "garmin.com.br",
    "garmin.pt",
    "garminfrance.com",
    "garmin.ro",
    "garmin.com.hr",
    "garmin.com.ar",
    "garmin.ca",
    "inreachdelorme.com"
  ],
  "site": {
    "title": "Garmin International | Home",
    "h1": "NEW VIRB® 360",
    "metaDescription": "Delivering innovative GPS technology across diverse markets, including aviation, marine, fitness, outdoor recreation, tracking and mobile apps.",
    "metaAuthor": "Garmin",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      "+1 913-397-8200"
    ],
    "emailAddresses": [
      "domain.admin@garmin.com",
      "productsupport.privacy@garmin.com",
      "webmaster@garmin.com",
      "garminsecurity@garmin.com",
      "copyright@garmin.com"
    ]
  },
  "category": {
    "sector": "Information Technology",
    "industryGroup": "Software & Services",
    "industry": "Internet Software & Services",
    "subIndustry": "Internet Software & Services",
    "sicCode": "3812",
    "naicsCode": null
  },
  "tags": [
    "Technology",
    "E-commerce",
    "Enterprise",
    "B2B",
    "B2C",
    "Consumer Discretionary",
    "Consumer Electronics"
  ],
  "description": "Delivering innovative GPS technology across diverse markets, including aviation, marine, fitness, outdoor recreation, tracking and mobile apps.",
  "foundedYear": 1989,
  "location": "Olathe, KS 66062, USA",
  "timeZone": "America/Chicago",
  "utcOffset": -5,
  "geo": {
    "streetNumber": null,
    "streetName": null,
    "subPremise": null,
    "city": "Olathe",
    "postalCode": "66062",
    "state": "Kansas",
    "stateCode": "KS",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "lat": 38.8271089,
    "lng": -94.7898731
  },
  "logo": "https://logo.clearbit.com/garmin.com",
  "facebook": {
    "handle": "garmin",
    "likes": 1542748
  },
  "linkedin": {
    "handle": "company/garmin-international"
  },
  "twitter": {
    "handle": "Garmin",
    "id": "15324722",
    "followers": 136976,
    "following": 812,
    "location": "at Garmin HQ just outside KC",
  },
  "crunchbase": {
    "handle": "organization/garmin"
  },
  "emailProvider": false,
  "type": "public",
  "ticker": "GRMN",
  "phone": "+41 52 630 16 00",
  "metrics": {
    "alexaUsRank": 1094,
    "alexaGlobalRank": 1535,
    "googleRank": null,
    "employees": 10000,
    "employeesRange": "1000+",
    "marketCap": 9800000000,
    "raised": null,
    "annualRevenue": 3018665000,
    "fiscalYearEnd": 12
  },
  "indexedAt": "2017-07-06T02:54:05.626Z",
  "tech": [
    "centos",
    "akamai_dns",
    "apache",
    "outlook",
    "microsoft_office_365",
    "google_analytics",
    "microsoft_exchange_online",
    "debian",
    "tealium",
    "youtube",
    "recaptcha"
  ],
  "similarDomains": [
    "cerner.com",
    "delorme.com",
    "fitbit.com",
    "google.com",
    "gpscity.com",
    "lowrance.com",
    "magellangps.com",
    "novatel.com",
    "polar.com",
    "suunto.com",
    "thegpsstore.com",
    "trimble.com"
  ]
}
```

^^ This is the kind of data that is stored in `[JSONDATA]` and we are going to be taking that data from the column and storing the data in the new columns that we made earlier with the ALTER TABLE query.

P.S. Can anyone explain the easiest way for me to remember and learn how to do this kind of modifications in the future by myself?

> I tried with but no luck:
>
> ```
>  WITH newvals AS (
>       SELECT * ,
>            JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.domain') AS Domain,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.name') AS CompanyName,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.legalName') AS legalName,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.sector') AS CategorySector,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.industryGroup') AS CategoryIndustryGroup,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.industry') AS CategoryIndustry,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.subIndustry') AS CategorySubIndustry,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.sicCode') AS CategorySicCode,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.naicsCode') AS CategoryNaicsCode,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.employees') AS EmployeesNumber,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.employeesRange') AS EmployeesRange,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.marketCap') AS MarketCap,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.annualRevenue') AS AnnualRevenue,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.parent.domain') AS ParentDomain
>       FROM [Domainbank].[dbo].[NoveDomeneAUG] nda
>      )
> UPDATE ad
>     SET CompanyName = newvals.CompanyName,
>         legalName = newvals.legalName,
>       CategorySector = newvals.CategorySector,
>       CategoryIndustryGroup = newvals.CategoryIndustryGroup,
>       CategoryIndustry = newvals.CategoryIndustry,
>       CategorySubIndustry = newvals.CategorySubIndustry,
>       CategorySicCode = newvals.CategorySicCode,
>       CategoryNaicsCode = newvals.CategoryNaicsCode,
>       EmployeesNumber = newvals.EmployeesNumber,
>       EmployeesRange = newvals.EmployeesRange,
>       MarketCap = newvals.MarketCap,
>       AnnualRevenue = newvals.AnnualRevenue,
>       ParentDomain = newvals.ParentDomain
>   FROM [Domainbank].[dbo].[NoveDomeneAUG] ad
>   INNER JOIN newvals
>   ON ad. = newvals. ;
> ```
>
> For this one I made a new table `[Domenetest]`, still no luck
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO [Domainbank].[dbo].[Domenetest]
>   SELECT JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.domain') AS Domain,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.name') AS CompanyName,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.legalName') AS legalName,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.sector') AS CategorySector,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.industryGroup') AS CategoryIndustryGroup,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.industry') AS CategoryIndustry,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.subIndustry') AS CategorySubIndustry,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.sicCode') AS CategorySicCode,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.category.naicsCode') AS CategoryNaicsCode,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.employees') AS EmployeesNumber,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.employeesRange') AS EmployeesRange,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.marketCap') AS MarketCap,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.metrics.annualRevenue') AS AnnualRevenue,
>              JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.parent.domain') AS ParentDomain
>       FROM [Domainbank].[dbo].[AugustDomain];
> ```

Comment: Well, you seem to be 80% here. Where specifically do you get stuck? You can see `UPDATE` examples at the bottom of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql . Looking at your question history I can see that people have shown you how to use update.

Comment: In the first example you have provided. You forgot to `INNER JOIN` your `newvals ` to your `NoveDomeneAUG` in the `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I updated the query but I still have some problems. What should I use at the last row on: "ON ad.??? = newvals.??? ;"

Comment: OK, lets start from the beginning. You don't need a "Common table expression" (`WITH newvals`) in your case. Since you are updating a table using the data form the same table all you do is write `UPDATE [your table] SET CompanyName = JSON_VALUE([JSONDATA], '$.name'), legalName = JSON_VALUE( ...` If you get any errors, make sure you post them, or provide a small sample, so that me (and other people) can reproduce it

Comment: Updated the Question again on the bottom.

Comment: You gotta try harder :) . You are missing comas after the second column

Comment: Ohh I see.. I didn't even spot that :O Now I just have to update the cells I got the error saying data would be truncated. I will put them to nvarchar(max)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help man! Will update now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query I was looking for:

> ```
> UPDATE [Domainbank].[dbo].[NoveDomeneAUG]
> SET 
> "CompanyName" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.name'), 
> "legalName" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.legalName'),
> "CategorySector" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.sector'),
> "CategoryIndustryGroup" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.industryGroup'),
> "CategoryIndustry" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.industry'),
> "CategorySubIndustry" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.subIndustry'),
> "CategorySicCode" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.sicCode'),
> "CategoryNaicsCode" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.category.naicsCode'),
> "EmployeesNumber" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.metrics.employees'),
> "EmployeesRange" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.metrics.employeesRange'),
> "MarketCap" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.metrics.marketCap'),
> "AnnualRevenue" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.metrics.annualRevenue'),
> "ParentDomain" = JSON_VALUE("JSONDATA", '$.parent.domain');
> ```